# How to set preference with numpy.select function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Following is my sample dataset:

```
Price  SL    X  
14    13.8  100
14.5  13.8   0
15    13.8   0
14.7  13.8   0
13.6  13.8   0
15    13.8   0
```

I want to create a new column that puts in remarks based on `X`. I want it to have `BUY` when `X` is `100`. Followed by three rows of `HOLD` and two rows of `SELL`.

I am doing this using the following code:

```
cond = [   
    (df['X'] == 100),
    (df['X'].shift(1) == 100),
    (df['X'].shift(2) == 100),
    (df['X'].shift(3) == 100),
    (df['X'].shift(4) == 100),
    (df['X'].shift(4) == 100),
]

choices = ['BUY', 'HOLD', 'HOLD', 'HOLD', 'SELL','SELL']
df['remarks'] = np.select(cond, choices)
```

Here is the outcome:

```
Price  SL    X    remarks
14    13.8  100    BUY
14.5  13.8   0     HOLD
15    13.8   0     HOLD
14.7  13.8   0     HOLD
13.6  13.8   0     SELL
15    13.8   0     SELL
```

However, I want to add another option of `Stopped Out` when `Price < SL` like in the fifth row. How do I assign `Stopped Out` the highest priority overall?

Desired outcome:

```
Price  SL    X    remarks
14    13.8  100    BUY
14.5  13.8   0     HOLD
15    13.8   0     HOLD
14.7  13.8   0     HOLD
13.6  13.8   0     Stopped Out
15    13.8   0     Stopped Out
14.5  13.8   0     
15    14.7  100    BUY
14.8  14.7   0     HOLD
13    14.7   0      Stopped Out
```

I would want the `remarks` to end once the `Stopped Out` shows up. And they should come up only after a `BUY` and not sometime before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add `default=''` to your current `np.select`:

```py
cond = [
    (df['X'] == 100),
    (df['X'].shift(1) == 100),
    (df['X'].shift(2) == 100),
    (df['X'].shift(3) == 100),
    (df['X'].shift(4) == 100),
    (df['X'].shift(4) == 100),
]
choices = ['BUY', 'HOLD', 'HOLD', 'HOLD', 'SELL','SELL']
df['remarks'] = np.select(cond, choices, default='')
#                                        ^^^^^^^^^^ add this
```

Then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) each `BUY` block and create a `stop` counter using a double [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```py
buy = df['X'].eq(100).cumsum()
df['stop'] = df.groupby(buy, sort=False).apply(lambda g: g['Price'].lt(g['SL']).cumsum().cumsum()).array

#    Price    SL    X remarks  stop
# 0   14.0  13.8  100     BUY     0
# 1   14.5  13.8    0    HOLD     0
# 2   15.0  13.8    0    HOLD     0
# 3   14.7  13.8    0    HOLD     0
# 4   13.6  13.8    0    SELL     1
# 5   15.0  13.8    0             2
# 6   14.5  13.8    0             3
# 7   15.0  14.7  100     BUY     0
# 8   14.8  14.7    0    HOLD     0
# 9   13.0  14.7    0    HOLD     1
```

Now [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) the `remarks` wherever `stop` is 1 or 2:

```py
df['remarks'] = df['remarks'].mask(df['stop'].isin([1, 2]), 'Stopped Out')

#    Price    SL    X      remarks
# 0   14.0  13.8  100          BUY
# 1   14.5  13.8    0         HOLD
# 2   15.0  13.8    0         HOLD
# 3   14.7  13.8    0         HOLD
# 4   13.6  13.8    0  Stopped Out
# 5   15.0  13.8    0  Stopped Out
# 6   14.5  13.8    0             
# 7   15.0  14.7  100          BUY
# 8   14.8  14.7    0         HOLD
# 9   13.0  14.7    0  Stopped Out
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I figured that none of the `stop` has `True` value because `SL` is calculated using `0.98*Price`. So,`Price` can't go below `SL` if it is calculated in every row. How can I use `SL` value from the `BUY` row?

Comment: I messed up with the sample data as it has fixed `SL`. The actual dataset has changing values.

Comment: see if the updated `stop` is what you're looking for (it compares against the `SL` of the first `BUY`)

Comment: So, with the most recent edit, SL is fixed at the first `X=100` value. And all it shows is `Stopped Out` :/

Comment: i fixed your sample df using `df.SL = 0.98*df.Price` and then ran the code from my answer. the result only shows `Stopped Out` starting from index 4. either i'm misunderstanding something or there's some significant difference in your real data.

Comment: There are several `X=100` in the actual data.

Comment: ah, so `Stopped Out` should only continue until the next `BUY`?

Comment: Yes. I should have mentioned it earlier. My bad

Comment: And to be clear. I only need `Stopped out` to continue until two rows when it first shows up. The `SL` should continue till the next `X=100`

Comment: I have edited the desired outcome in my question

Comment: @Strugglingbrat ok i think the updated answer should match your expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

How about using `iloc`?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Price':[14,14.5,15,14.7,13.6,15],
                  'SL':[13.8,13.8,13.8,13.8,13.8,13.8],
                  'X':[100,0,0,0,0,0]}) 

choices = ['BUY', 'HOLD', 'HOLD', 'HOLD', 'SELL', 'SELL']
df['remarks'] = choices

df.iloc[df[df['Price'] < df['SL']].index[0]: , -1] = 'Stopped Out'
```

[image: Results]

Comment: My actual data is a lot bigger. I will need to have a choice for each index. Presently, it gives out a value error. `ValueError: Length of values (6) does not match length of index (84246)`

Answer (score 0):

The condition are evaluated sequentially so insert your condition with highest priority at the top of the list:

```
cond = [
    (df['Price'] < df['SL']),  # <- HERE
    (df['X'] == 100),
    (df['X'].shift(1) == 100),
    (df['X'].shift(2) == 100),
    (df['X'].shift(3) == 100),
    (df['X'].shift(4) == 100),
    (df['X'].shift(4) == 100),
]

choices = ['Stopped Out', 'BUY', 'HOLD', 'HOLD', 'HOLD', 'SELL','SELL']

df['remarks'] = np.select(cond, choices)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would want the remarks to end once stopped out shows up. Presently, the `HOLD` and `SELL` go on as usual even after `Stopped Out`.